# Sagemaker training job Fatal error: cannot open file 'train': No such file or directory

Tags: r, amazon-sagemaker, serverless.com

I am trying work on bring your own model. I have R code. when i try to run the job its failing.

**Training Image:**

```
FROM r-base:3.6.3

MAINTAINER Amazon SageMaker Examples <amazon-sagemaker-examples@amazon.com>

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    wget \
    r-base \
    r-base-dev \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    python3 python3-dev pip

ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-2"
RUN R -e "install.packages('reticulate', dependencies = TRUE, warning = function(w) stop(w))"
RUN R -e "install.packages('readr', dependencies = TRUE, warning = function(w) stop(w))"
RUN R -e "install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE, warning = function(w) stop(w))"

RUN pip install --quiet --no-cache-dir \
    'boto3>1.0<2.0' \
    'sagemaker>2.0<3.0'    

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/Rscript"]
```

**Source code:**

```
rcode
    └── train.R
    └── train.tar.gz
```

Build

```
- aws s3 cp $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/rcode/ s3://${self:custom.deploymentBucket}/${self:service}/code/training --recursive
```

**Serverless.com yaml**

```
           SagemakerRCodeTrainingStep:
            Type: Task
            Resource: ${self:custom.sageMakerTrainingJob}
            Parameters:
              TrainingJobName.$: "$.sageMakerTrainingJobName"
              DebugHookConfig:
                S3OutputPath: "s3://${self:custom.deploymentBucket}/${self:service}/models/rmodel"
              AlgorithmSpecification:
                TrainingImage: ${self:custom.sagemakerRExecutionContainerURI}
                TrainingInputMode: "File"
              OutputDataConfig:
                S3OutputPath: "s3://${self:custom.deploymentBucket}/${self:service}/models/rmodel"
              StoppingCondition:
                MaxRuntimeInSeconds: ${self:custom.maxRuntime}
              ResourceConfig:
                InstanceCount: 1
                InstanceType: "ml.m5.xlarge"
                VolumeSizeInGB: 30
              RoleArn: ${self:custom.stateMachineRoleARN}
              InputDataConfig:
                - DataSource:
                    S3DataSource:
                      S3DataType: "S3Prefix"
                      S3Uri: "s3://${self:custom.datasetsFilePath}/data/processed/train"
                      S3DataDistributionType: "FullyReplicated"
                  ChannelName: "train"
              HyperParameters:
                sagemaker_submit_directory: "s3://${self:custom.deploymentBucket}/${self:service}/code/training/train.tar.gz"
                sagemaker_program: "train.R"
                sagemaker_enable_cloudwatch_metrics: "false"
                sagemaker_container_log_level: "20"
                sagemaker_job_name: "sagemaker-r-learn-2022-02-28-09-56-33-234"
                sagemaker_region: ${self:provider.region}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which `TrainingImage` you are using and all the files in your container.
That being said, I suspect you are using a custom container.

SageMaker Training Jobs look for a `train` file and run your container as [follows](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-dockerfile.html):

```
docker run image train
```

You can change this behavior by setting the `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile. Please see this example [Dockerfile](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/r_examples/r_byo_r_algo_hpo/Dockerfile#L47) from the [r_byo_r_algo_hpo](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/r_examples/r_byo_r_algo_hpo) example.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try this. But if i add  model code along with docker files, then each time there is change in model code docker has to be build. I want to keep docker repo and R model code repo separate.  Is there anyway for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ability to execute an arbitrary R script inside your container, you will need to write an entrypoint R script that takes uses the arguments Sagemaker passes in.  [The Amazon Sagemaker example repo cover this here](https://github.com/aws-samples/rstudio-on-sagemaker-workshop/tree/main/02_AdvancedSageMaker).  Using the `entrypoint` parameter of the [Sagemaker SDK estimator class](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html), the name of your script will passed as an argument in the run command (e.g. `docker run image train script`).

Note that the `entrypoint` argument to the estimator class is *not* overriding the image's entrypoint as you might expect based on the name.  It is only adding an argument to the `docker run` command.